# How to formulate a conditional sum in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing `id`, `category`, `noofquestions` and `company`. I want a query which would return the `noofquestions` as sum of the values of `noofquestions` when `category` is same in two or more columns. I'm trying this query but it is only adding those columns whose category is same and `noofquestions` are equal which is wrong. It should not check for `noofquestions`.

```
 SELECT id ,  category,   SUM(NULLIF(noofquestions, '')::int), company 
 FROM tableName   
 WHERE id=1 
 GROUP BY id, category, noofquestions, company;
```

Comment: "not working properly"? Um. Edited to provide meaningful title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not group by `noofquestions`:

```
SELECT   id, category, SUM(NULLIF(noofquestions, '')::int), company 
FROM     tableName 
WHERE    id = 1 
GROUP BY id, category, company;
```

Comment: this is working, but explain the behavior a little if you may.

Comment: Aggregate functions like `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN` and `MAX` on a table column  require the table column in question to be excluded from the `GROUP BY` clause in order to achieve the desired results.

Comment: If you use GROUP BY, then you return one row for each combination of the things in your GROUP BY statement. Any aggregations (like SUM) you put into the select are then used to turn many rows from your original table into a single row in your result. So, if you want to sum together rows with different values of noofquestions, it can't be in your GROUP BY statement.